# Possible to use Vimeo npmjs in Angular App?

Tags: angular, vimeo

I have an Angular app. The vimeo npmjs component looks like it's pure JS. I'd like my Angular app to call my vimeo account, and first pull a list of thumbnails from a collection and display them in a list, and then when the user clicks on one, pop a modal viewer and call the API for the video. Is this possible? The sample code from vimeo throws a "Failed to compile" error in Anguar... i replaced the three placeholders with my actual values (client_id, etc).

```
let Vimeo = require('vimeo').Vimeo;
let client = new Vimeo("{client_id}", "{client_secret}", "{access_token}");

client.request({
  method: 'GET',
  path: '/tutorial'
}, function (error, body, status_code, headers) {
  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }

  console.log(body);
})
```

Comment: Use [this library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@mintplayer/ng-vimeo-player)